# Could not pass array value from Javascript to Codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, parameters

In my HTML, when a user selects from a dropdown option, the selected item is stored in a Javascript variable. I'm trying to pass this value(s) to my controller variable in CodeIgniter, but it fails.

**Here's my HTML code:**

```
<form name="change_app_formTrader" id="change_app_formTrader">
    <label>Approver Name</label>
    <select name="app_id[]">
        <option value="0">select approver</option>
        <option value="approver1">Approver One</option>
        <option value="approver2">Approver Two</option>
        <option value="approver3">Approver Three</option>
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="save_appchangeteto()" value="Save Changes"/>
```

**Here's my javascript code for save_appchangeteto():**

```
var tetoApprover;
var appword;

function save_appchangeteto(){
    tetoApprover = [];
    appword = '';
    var appid   = 0;

    $('form[name="change_app_formTrader"]').find(':input').each(function(){
        appid = $(this).val();
        appword = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
        push_approverteto(appid,appword);
    });
    populate_approverteto();

} /*save_appchangeteto()*/

function push_approverteto(appid,appword){
    tetoApprover.push({
        'appid':appid,
        'appword':appword
    });
}

function populate_approverteto(){
    var htm = '';
    var x = 0;
    $.each(tetoApprover,function(){
        x+=1;
        htm += '<tr>';
            htm += '<td>'+x+'</td>';
            htm += '<td>'+this.appword+'</td>';
            htm +='<td></td>';
            htm +='<td></td>';
            htm += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#approverTblTrader').html(htm);
} /*populate_approverteto*/
```

**Then when the user clicks the submit button, it executes the below code:**

```
$('#submitTradersRequest').click(function(){
    $('.rc-loader').html('<img src="'+BASE_URL+'assets/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>&nbsp;Please wait..');
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);

    tetoApprover = (tetoApprover.length<1)?1:tetoApprover;
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+'create/process',
        type: "POST",
        data: {approvers:tetoApprover},

        success: function(data){
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(response.status!='Success'){
                $('.rc-loader').html('<span class="alert alert-error">'+response.msg+'</span>');
            }
        }
    }).fail(function() { alert('Error'); });

    $(this).prop('disabled',false);
});
```

**But in my controller, the `tetoApprover` was not passed at all. The code executed was the one inside the else below, which means the variable for approvers has no value at all:**

```
$post = $this->input->post();
if($post['approvers']){
    foreach($post['approvers'] as $val){
        $count++;
        $status = 0;
        $token = sha1(rand().date('m/d/y'));
        if($count==1){
            $status = 1;
        }
        $params = array('scalar'=>array(
            $reqid,
            $val['appid']
        )
        );
        $this->create_model->updatestatus($params);
    }
}
else { //this is where the process currently goes
    $val['appid'] = 4; //test
    $params = array('scalar'=>array(
        $reqid,
        $val['appid']
    ));
    $this->create_model->updatestatus($params);
}
```

I've been working on this for days, but could not find where I went wrong. Please help.

**UPDATE:**

I have confirmed that `push_approverteto()` is working properly because `populate_approverteto()` is successfully updating the list of approvers on the display.

In other words, the values are successfully saved in the variable `tetoApprover`.

However, it fails to be passed to the controller variable `$post['approvers']`. That is my main problem because i could not save the user-given values into my database.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have error in function param.

```
public function create($process='0')
{
     if($proces='0' or !isset($proces)) return false;
     //do something
}
```

And update your ajax param:

```
url: BASE_URL+'create/1'
```

Look. In this example **1** in ajax method was **$process** in php.
If you trying to send ajax request to *BASE_URL+'create/process'* url, you have php-error, because param not isset or type of param not type of param in request.

P.S.: sorry for my English.